# Binomial classification using a list comprehension python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm working with `pandas`, and I want to add a new `Serie` with a binomial classification if a word is within a sentence.

For example:

```
year = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012]
state = ['hello', 'my friend', 'hello and', 'coding', 'python', 'hello', 'who is', 'hello, friend']
data = {'year': Series(year), 'state': Series(state)}
pd = DataFrame(data)
```

So I tried this to get 1 or 0 if 'hello' is in item from state list.

```
data['hello'] = []
for item in data['state']:
    if 'hello' in item:
        data['hello'].append(1)
    else:
        data['hello'].append(0)
```

However, is there a method te get a binomial classification using a `list comprehension`

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible list comprehension equivalent is:

```
data['hello'] = [(1 if 'hello' in item else 0) for item in data['state']]
```

If True/False is acceptable:

```
data['hello'] = ['hello' in item for item in data['state']]
```

Comment: The first example is a great solution. Excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about using `pandas` [`Series.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling):

```
>>> pd['hello'] =  pd['state'].str.contains('hello')
>>> pd
           state  year  hello
0          hello  2010   True
1      my friend  2011  False
2      hello and  2012   True
3         coding  2011  False
4         python  2012  False
5          hello  2010   True
6         who is  2011  False
7  hello, friend  2012   True
```

Not a list comprehension, but possibly what you (may not have known you) were looking for.